# Find a vector in the null space of a large dense matrix, where elements in the matrix are not directly accessible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis

I am working with Conjugate Gradient method to solve for =, where  is an extremely large PSD and Singular matrix. I cannot directly access the elements of . The only thing I can do is computing  for any vector , which is a rather expensive operation.

Now, I would like to solve for =0, which is effectively finding one vector in the null space of . I understand that it is slow to solve it with CG directly. I wonder if there are other iterative methods that would give a reasonably good solution with only the access of  very quickly?

Comment: Why would CG be slow on this? The progress of CG depends on the full spectrum of A and not so much on the condition number if I remember correctly.

Comment: I mean CG is for sure the fastest iterative method to solve for any general equations Ax=b (A being PSD). However, for the particular case Ax=0, CG is obviously not utilising the information of b = 0. I wonder if I could incorporate this information to improve the convergence speed of CG, or, if there are other methods that are particularly efficient in solving Ax = 0.